# Laravel 5.2 request validation with Dingo(JWT) Api

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

Laravel 5.2 request validation is not working in dingo(JWT) API.

When I try to call controller method I use request validation that time it returns blow error.

**Error**
{"message":"500 Internal Server Error","status_code":500}

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Api\V1\Controllers;

  //use App\Http\Requests;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Api\V1\Controllers\ApiController;
  use App\Http\Requests\StoreBlogPost;
  //use Request;
  use DB;

  class CommonController extends ApiController {

  public function getCabinet(StoreBlogPost $request) {
  $postData = $request->all();
  $floorkey = $postData ['FloorKey'];

  }

  }
```

**Request**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

  use App\Http\Requests\Request;

  class StoreBlogPost extends Request {

  /**
  * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
  *
  * @return bool
  */
  public function authorize() {
  return False;
  }

  /**
  * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
  *
  * @return array
  */
  public function rules() {
  return [
  'FloorKey' => 'required',
  ];
  }

  public function response(array $error) {
  //Can't get json responce validation error in Controller 
  return response()->json(['error' => $error], 422);
  }

  }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what have you done till now?

Comment: @RahulSharma this is my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change request class `App\Http\Requests\Request` to `Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest`